# What is "La Leĝo de Tonjo"?

Tags: culture

I've heard esperantists mention "La Leĝo de Tonjo" but I'm not sure what it means. Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The *Leĝo de Tonjo* is a humorous law mocking the fact that a large portion of conversations in Esperanto end up getting derailed by a discussion about grammar. The original text of the law is:

> Ju pli reta diskuto en Esperanto longas, la probableco ke ĝi deflankiĝos al diskuto pri gramatikaĵoj aŭ pri la uzata vortigo des pli (asimptote) proksimiĝas al 1.

A rough translation would be:

> The longer an internet discussion in Esperanto gets, the more the probability that it will get side-tracked into a discussion about grammatical points or the usage of a word approaches 1

It is written in an overly scientific style to make it seem more official, but it is just stating that a long internet conversation in Esperanto is bound to eventually end up with a pedantic talk about the language usage.

It is inspired by [Godwin's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godwin%27s_law) which is as follows:

> As an online discussion grows longer, the probability of a comparison involving Nazism or Hitler approaches 1

This makes a similar point that *any* internet conversation will eventually make a reference to Nazism or Hitler. I guess in the case of conversations in Esperanto that likely means the conversation will first become a heated debate about grammar and then if it continues then one of the parties will angrily accuse the other of behaving like Hitler.

[image: Ekzemplo de la leĝoj de Tonjo kaj Godwin]

Comment: Interesa respondo, sed... Kiu estas Tonjo? 

Comment: _José Antonio del Barrio_, pli konata kiel Toño (aŭ Tonyo, aŭ Tonjo). Vi povas sufiĉe facile trovi en la reto liajn paĝojn. Lian leĝon vidu ĉi tie: http://www.delbarrio.eu/2008/04/la-legho-de-tonjo.htm.